# android selectableItemBackground selection

Tags: android, android-selector

i want to change background of my view when the state is "activated" and i want to preserve the effects(ripple) of `?attr:selectableItemBackground`. Is it possible to extend or combine selector of `?attr:selectableItemBackground`?

Answer (score 19):

You can use a [`LayerDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) in order to draw the ripple effect drawable (`?attr:selectableItemBackground`) over your activated state color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <selector>
            <item android:state_activated="true">
                <color android:color="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
            </item>
            <item>
                <color android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            </item>
        </selector>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
</layer-list>
```

**Edit:**
As it's not possible to use theme attributes in an XML drawable before API 21, it seems to be better to put the ripple effect drawable as a foreground drawable, and the activated color selector drawable as a background drawable.

```
<View
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/yourView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:background="@drawable/activated_color_selector">
```

With `res/drawable/activated_color_selector.xml` containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true">
        <!-- Can't use the ?attr/colorPrimary before API 21 -->
        <color android:color="@color/primaryColor"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <color android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: This will only work on Lollipop and up... will crash with unknown class exception on Kitkat and lower devices.

Comment: Yeah true... I just discovered that it's not possible to use theme attributes in drawable XML until Lollipop.

Answer (score 3):

For those who only care about API >= 21 now in 2020, here's a simpler solution :

```xml
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?colorControlHighlight">
    <!--  the ripple's color (1) -->

    <!--  no `id` so our <shape> will be drawn and not just used as mask -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="9dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

> `(1)` If you don't override `colorControlHighlight` in your theme, the ripple's color will be Android's default. If you *do* override it in your theme but want to use Android's default for a specific case use `?android:colorControlHighlight` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To change ripple color throughout the app you can ad this in your app theme

```
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ripple</item>
```

Comment: i don't want to change the ripple color, i want to change background color when the state is "activated" i.e. selected.

Comment: You can add a background color and add clickable = true for ripple color

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way I found is to have additional view in your layour that will emulate the selected state. Like so (works on pre-Lollipop as well):

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/item_selected"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorControlHighlight"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Then in your adapter you set visibility of `item_selected` to either `View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE`, based on the need to make this particular item selected.

**P.S.** Obviously, this solution uses *AppCompat* support library, so in order to use it the following line should be added to `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by swapping the background drawables at runtime. This code runs in `onBindViewHolder` in `RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>`:

```
if (selected) {
    itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_background);
} else {            
    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
          new int[]{android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground});
    itemView.setBackgroundResource(typedArray.getResourceId(0, 0));
    typedArray.recycle();
}
```

The `R.drawable.selected_background` refers to the background of a selected item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccentLight" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Another solution is to have two identical item types except for different backgrounds but that seems to be an overkill.