# How to set selectableItemBackground Ripple on Selector

Tags: android, user-interface, android-constraintlayout

I have a `RecyclerView` with a `ConstraintLayout` as the root `View` of each item.

I am setting the `ConstraintLayout` background as a `selector`, the `selector` is defined as:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?attr/selectableItemBackground" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

My goal was to have the ripple effect when an item is pressed, and change the item's background to the accent color when the item is selected.

The problem is, `selectableItemBackground` works on any `View`'s `background`, but if I place it on the selector as it is, my app crashes as soon as the `ConstraintLayout` is inflated.

If I remove the `?attr/selectableItemBackground` and substitute it for any color, the `selector` works just fine.

Here's the simplified crash error on Logcat:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: 
        Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout                                                                 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: 
        Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout                                                                            
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
        Drawable com.test.test:drawable/list_item_background_selector with resource ID #0x7f080086
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
        File res/drawable/list_item_background_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080086
```

Comment: Why not `android:foreground="android:?attr/selectableItemBackground"` on the XML layout, then set your background as you wish?

Comment: That works! Great idea...but still it bugs me why it doesn't work on the selector...I usually like to understand why something doesn't work, and not just settle for a workaround...any clues what's happenings?

Comment: Not without delving into the source. Although I don't like the term "Whatever works" sometimes life is easier settling with it!

Comment: yeah, that should be on a t-shirt for coders or something ...

Comment: Just for reference, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36424426/8781554) seems to do the trick.